# Object scaling on rotating perspective camera on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am just looking to know if the objects are supposed to scale noticeably when rotating the camera up and down (and right, left).

I get how it becomes a little more realistic with a little scaling but what I am seeing is the object scaling is very noticeable and looks unrealistic.

Is this supposed to be the normal behavior of the camera and if so can it be configured?

(As you can tell I am a unity noob)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is that you have a very strong "FishEye" effect on the camera. Did you try to reduce the `Field of View` of the `Camera` component? Or in case you have `Physical Camera` enabled, increase the `Focal Length`

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for your advice. I have played a little with the orthographic camera as well. Do you think for a 3d augmented reality application should I be using an orthographic or perspective camera?

Comment: This depends of how you want it to look like. But I'ld never use the orthographic camera if it shall look somehow near to real. But is also depends a bit if you want to display it on a 2D device like a tablet or on a 3D device like any MR glasses (always go for perspective camera if possible)

Comment: Great. Thanks ;)